# Should we use "Where" to mention the place of birth or should not?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

This is the question:

> Tell me about the town ----- you grew up.

1. That
2. Where
3. (none of the above)

Answer (score 1):

"Where" is fine:

1. Tell me about the town where you grew up. (simplest and most common usage)
2. Tell me about the town that you grew up **in**. (colloquial but pedants may object)
3. Tell me about the town **in which** you grew up. (very correct but rather formal)

I can't explain the rules. I'm not a grammarian.

Comment: Your second sentence is gramatticaly incorrect as it ends in a preposition.

Comment: You're right. Well spotted.

Comment: @Chenmunka that "rule" is widely contested (see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16/92798 and sources linked therein). The second option sounds completely natural.

Comment: @Chenmunka "English" Grammar does not have such a rule.

Comment: I told you I'm not a grammarian.

Comment: @Chenmunka I thought your comment was a joke. Well, it is still a joke, but in a different way: the statement that a sentence can or should not end in a preposition is a joke.

Comment: It is something up with which I will not put.

Comment: That "rule" is just something that some grammarian made up.